# Find and replace all the same words in one file in Shell

Tags: bash, shell, replace, sed

I want to find all the same words inside one file and replace them with the same words. How can I do it? I know that I can do it with `sed -i 's/old-word/new-word/g' *.txt`, but I need to change all the same words. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "all the same words"?

Comment: Better add sample input/output

Comment: for example, I have 7 "brother" words inside my file. I must replace them with "sister" words.

Comment: Show sample input and expected output. `I have 7 "brother" words inside my file` does not mean anything, or could mean many things.

Comment: Lorem ipsum `brother` sit amet. My `brother` is elder than me.

Comment: why doesn't `s/brother/sister/g` work on the above?

Comment: It changes all the `brother` words?

Comment: That seems to be what you're asking for. Simply update your question to show sample input and expected output because clearly no-one can figure out what it is you're trying to do. It should be very quick and easy for you to just provide what we're asking for to help you. Right now you're wasting a lot of people's time.

Comment: Do you mean occurrences of the word "brother"? By word, do you mean not strings like brotherhood but only brother preceded and followed by blanks or puctuation chars?

Comment: yes, only and only `brother`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really unclear what you are asking, but here is a guess:

```
$ cat input
my brother, brothers in the brotherhood

$ sed 's/\<brother\(s\)\?\>/sister\1/g' input
my sister, sisters in the brotherhood
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I ask: I need to change only `brother`, not `Brother` or `brothers` or `brotherhood`. Thanks!